# Taking Partial Derivatives of the function $F=F(\xi,\phi) \quad\text{where}\quad \xi=\frac{h}{h_*} \text{ and } \phi=\frac{\psi}{h}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm working through a paper where the author has defined functions of functions. The example I am trying to understand involves the following definitions given in the paper:
$$ F=F(\xi,\phi) \quad\text{where}\quad \xi=\frac{h}{h_*} \text{ and } \phi=\frac{\psi}{h} $$
where even further:
$$ h=h(\vec{x},t), \quad \psi=\psi(\vec{x},t) $$
Now I am trying to understand what to make of one term that appears: $\nabla F_\xi$. Would it be correct that:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(F_\xi) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial h}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}(F_\xi) + \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial h}\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi}(F_\xi) $$
and then a similar form for the other components of $\nabla F_\xi$?

Comment: Do they define $F_\xi$?

Comment: Later on in the paper, the author prescibes $F$ a specific form based on "a combination of power laws". But while the paper is deriving the equation where this calculation arises there is no explicit form given for the function. I am actually just trying to fill in the intermediary steps to get to an expression they later show which involves terms that include $F_{\xi\xi}$

Comment: @Paradox I believe $F_\xi := \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial\xi}$ in this context.

Comment: what is the term $h_*$?

Comment: $h_*$ is a parameter in the problem. Also, yes the comment above is correct in that $F_\xi := \frac{\partial F}{\partial \xi}$